# why openerp web module is displaying loading

Tags: odoo, openerp-8, openerp-web-module

I am developing a new openerp web module from scratch. I am trying to use the same concept used in the Point Of Sale web module that comes with OpenERP.

This is my controller method that is handling the web url:

```
@http.route('/university/', auth='public')
    def index(self, **kw):
        cr, uid, context, session = request.cr, request.uid,      request.context, request.session
          modules =  simplejson.dumps(module_boot(request.db))
          init =  """
                 var wc = new s.web.WebClient();
                 wc._title_changed = function() {}
                 wc.show_application = function(){
                 wc.action_manager.do_action("university.ui");
                };
                wc.setElement($(document.body));
                wc.start();
                 """

        html = request.registry.get('ir.ui.view').render(cr,     session.uid,'university.index',{
            'modules': modules,
            'init': init,
        })

        return html
enter code here
```

the page source generated when the page loads is the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Odoo POS</title>

        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1"/>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html, charset=utf-8"/>

        <meta name="viewport" content=" width=1024, user-scalable=no"/>
        <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes"/>
        <meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes"/>

        <link rel="shortcut icon" sizes="196x196"     href="/point_of_sale/static/src/img/touch-icon-196.png"/>
        <link rel="shortcut icon" sizes="128x128"     href="/point_of_sale/static/src/img/touch-icon-128.png"/>
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/point_of_sale/static/src/img/touch-icon-iphone.png"/>
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="76x76" href="/point_of_sale/static/src/img/touch-icon-ipad.png"/>
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="120x120" href="/point_of_sale/static/src/img/touch-icon-iphone-retina.png"/>
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="152x152" href="/point_of_sale/static/src/img/touch-icon-ipad-retina.png"/>

        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/web/static/src/img/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/point_of_sale/static/src/fonts/lato/stylesheet.css"/> 
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/point_of_sale/static/src/fonts/font-awesome-4.0.3/css/font-awesome.min.css"/> 
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/point_of_sale/static/src/css/pos.css" id="pos-stylesheet"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/point_of_sale/static/src/css/keyboard.css"/>


            <script type="text/javascript" src="/web/js/web.assets_common/d535558"></script>

            <script type="text/javascript" src="/web/js/web.assets_backend/ec9370d"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript" id="loading-script">
            $(function() {
            var s = new openerp.init(["web", "web_kanban", "base",     "base_setup", "mail", "email_template", "edi", "share", "report", "product",     "board", "account", "account_voucher", "point_of_sale", "account_accountant",     "web_calendar", "calendar", "l10n_ae", "web_tests", "bus", "im_chat",     "im_odoo_support", "base_import", "web_view_editor", "web_gantt", "portal",     "student", "payment", "web_kanban_sparkline", "purchase", "web_diagram",     "university", "sales_team", "sale", "web_example", "payment_transfer",     "web_kanban_gauge", "stock", "web_graph", "crm"]);

                 var wc = new s.web.WebClient();
                 wc._title_changed = function() {}
                 wc.show_application = function(){
                     wc.action_manager.do_action("pos.ui");
                 };
                 wc.setElement($(document.body));
                 wc.start();

            });
        </script>

    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="openerp openerp_webclient_container">
            <table class="oe_webclient">
                <tr>
                    <td class="oe_application"></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

When the page loads, it will display all my widgets successfully, but it will display at the bottom of the page "Loading..."

why this loading is displayed, and how to remove it.

Appreciate your response